# shortest way to find absolute min. of two number & multiply it with signs of its inputs in AVX

Tags: simd, avx, avx2

Any hint on how to implement AVX for below C logic without multiplications,

```
for(int i = 0;i<4096;i++)
{
   out[i] = sign(inp1[i])*sign(inp2[i])*min(abs(inp1[i]), abs(inp2[i])); 
}
```

// inp1, inp2 & out are 16 bit registers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is pretty short (but non-obvious) solution to your problem:

```
res = max(min(a,b), -max(a,b));
```

(All min/max operations are signed)

To explain why this works, first let us set

```
A = min(a,b); B = max(a,b);
```

This essentially sorts `a` and `b` (and rules out the case that `A>0 && B<0`). We now just need to distinguish 3 cases:

```
A<0  && B<0:     res = -B 
A<0  && B>=0:    res = -min(-A, B) = max(A, -B)
A>=0 && B>=0:    res = A
```

Fortunately, the first and last case can also be calculated as `max(A,-B)`, since in the first case `A < 0 < -B`, and in the last case `-B <= 0 <= A`.

<strike>Alternatively, you could just ask (and trust) [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sign%28a%29*sign%28b%29*min%28abs%28a%29%2C+abs%28b%29%29+%3D+max%28min%28a%2Cb%29%2C+-max%28a%2Cb%29%29).</strike> (not really helpful, as it only evaluates to true "assuming a and b are positive" -- you could plot the difference between both expressions though)

---

Implementing this with AVX2 (ignoring loading and storing):

```
__m256i A = _mm256_min_epi16(a,b);
__m256i B = _mm256_max_epi16(a,b);
__m256i res = _mm256_max_epi16(A, _mm256_sub_epi16(_mm256_setzero_si256(), B));
```

The `setzero` operation will happen outside any loop, so for each packet there are three min/max-operations and one psub-operation. On Intel-CPUs the first execute on ports `p01`, while `psub` executes on any `p015`, so the loop would bottle-neck on `p01`, requiring 1.5cycles per packet.

As noted by @Soonts, the `-B` operation can overflow, for `B=-0x8000` (there is no positive `0x8000` for signed int16). This only happens for `a=b=-0x8000`. If you prefer to output `0x7fff` in that case, you can replace the subtraction by a saturated subtraction (`_mm256_subs_epi16`).

Comment: Nice one; this is significantly better than my idea, OP should accept this answer.

Comment: Good answer but it has a bug, absolute and unary minus may overflow for integers.
Fortunately, it’s easy to fix here and the fix is free performance-wise, replace `_mm256_sub_epi16` instruction with `_mm256_subs_epi16`.

Comment: @Soonts I think the issue would only occur for `a==b==-0x8000` (in which case it will output `0x8000`, (where `+0x8000` is meant, but of course for signed integers this will be seen as negative). I'll add a note on that.

Answer (score 3):

The  `sign(inp1[i])*sign(inp2[i])` part can **almost** exactly be implemented with [`_mm256_sign_epi16(in1, in2)`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/psignb:psignw:psignd), and using that as the 2nd operand to another `vpsignw` to apply the sign of that to the `min(abs,abs)` result.

**`psignw` negates *or zeroes* the first operand, depending on the 2nd operand being negative or zero.**    ([Intrinsics guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX2,AVX_512,Other&text=psign&expand=5222,5223)).  (We don't need the zeroing part of `psignw`: if either input is zero, unsigned min of their absolute values will be zero.  But we have to *avoid* it depending on how we generate an input, if that can happen when neither of our real inputs are zero.)

**There's a corner case where that's wrong: in1 = INT16_MIN = 0x8000, in2<0**.  The result of negating `in1` would still be negative; thanks to the 2's complement most negative number not having an inverse.

**If one of the 2 values can't be `0x8000`, use that as the 1st arg to `_mm256_sign_epi16` with no extra operations needed.**

@chtz proposes a workaround strategy: XOR the inputs together to get the right value for the sign bit.  But that will trigger `vpsignw`'s zeroing behaviour for in1==in2 because in1^in2==0.  You could `or` with `set1(1)` on the XOR result to make sure it's non-zero.

```
// pseudocode because the full intrinsic names are long and hard to read / type
    sign = (in1 ^ in2) | 1;
    out = psignw( min(abs1,abs2), sign);
  // operation count: XOR, OR, PSIGNW = 3 plus min(abs,abs)
```

On Skylake, `vpsignw` can run on execution ports p0 or p1.  Booleans like `vpxor` and `vpor` can run on any of p0, p1, or p5. (https://uops.info/)  So this way is potentially better than the other idea which uses `psignw` twice.  It "couples" together the dependency chains of both operands earlier, by 1 instruction, but probably this will be throughput limited even if data is coming from another operation in the same pass.

`pabsw` and `pminuw` both also need p0 / p1, can't run on p5, so picking the same number of instructions but using ones that *can* utilize port 5 leads to a better balance of execution port pressure for the back-end on Skylake.  Zen2 is somewhat similar, with booleans able to run on any FP execution port (0/1/2/3) but `psignw` / `pabsw` only FP0 / FP3, and `pminuw` only FP0/1/3.

---

Another option is to avoid `psignw` entirely instead of working around its zeroing behaviour: XOR and then broadcast the sign bit with arithmetic right shift, then implement conditional negation with the 2's complement identity `-x = ~x - (-1)`.  But that costs one more operation.

```
    sign = (in1 ^ in2) >> 15;   // pxor  psraw
    out =  (min(abs1,abs2) ^ sign) - sign;  // pxor, psubw
  // operation count: XOR, shift, XOR, SUB = 4 plus min(abs,abs)
```

---

Another workaround idea was `_mm256_or_si256(in1, _mm256_set1_epi16(1))` before `vpsignw` to make sure the value has the same sign but isn't `INT16_MIN`.

```
// not as good as 
   sign = psignw(in1 | 1, in2);   // VPOR, VPSIGNW
   out = psignw( min(abs1,abs2), sign);
// operation count: OR, 2x PSIGNW = 3 plus min(abs,abs)
```

An arithmetic right shift by 1 wouldn't be safe: it could make the operand zero when the input was `1`, resulting in a final output of zero for an input of `1, 2`

---

IDK if there's any clever trick that would be better than [`vpabsw`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pabsb:pabsw:pabsd:pabsq) on each input separately to feed [`vpminuw`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pminub:pminuw)

Comment: `sign(inp1[i])*sign(inp2[i])` could also be computed using `_mm256_xor_si256(inp1[i],inp2[i])`, since only the upper bit is relevant (will also use `p5` on most (all?) Intel CPUs). I think I found an alternative way which takes `3p01+3p015` (instead of `4p01+1p015`) -- this would only be useful, when mixed with your solution (need to check it, though).

Comment: Actually `_mm256_sign_epi16(in1, in2)` is wrong (or not the intended result), if `in1<0` and `in2 = -0x8000`.

Comment: @chtz: Integer VPXOR can run on any port on Intel CPUs.  You're thinking of `vxorps`.  I considered that but worried it could create a `0` when both inputs are the same, so the next `vpsignw` would zero the result.  e.g. with in1=in2=anything.  We could work around that by ORing in a non-zero low bit into the XOR result.

Comment: Indeed, this is a problem (but so is the edge-case with `-0x8000`). I'll write down my alternative solution (I'm pretty sure it works).

Comment: Just read your workaround-edit. Yes, this should solve all issues (I think)

Comment: @chtz: finished writing up some perf analysis and example code blocks.  If anyone wants to turn one of them into proper intrinsics syntax for a whole loop, that would be fine; I simply didn't bother.

Comment: I miscalculated the port-usage on my first idea, but actually found a much easier solution now. It's just `3p01+1p015`.

Comment: Thanks to @Peter Cordes for your time & work. Your comments & hints will surely make my day busy.

Comment: As only one user can be notified at a time, thanking @chtz too with same intention.

Comment: @user49626: you should probably accept chtz's answer; it's more efficient and thus the better choice for future readers.